# Tooltipster Multiple trigger events for single tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

I am using jQuery plugin Tooltipster. I want tooltip to be shown by both, click and hover events. How can i do this?

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
   trigger: 'hover' // I want to have also click event here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try the experimental Tooltipster v4 on the v4 branch of the project, it has this feature (using the triggerOpen option). All the necessary documentation is included.